# Stop Tkinter grid from changing size

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a music player that displays the song name in a Label, which is in a grid. My entire window resizes if a song is long enough, but it doesn't need to. Is there a way to either make a row that has one column in it, or a way to just make the window stop resizing?

```
self.search_results = tk.Label(master, text=self.query, bg="#eeac41", fg="#000000") 
self.search_results.grid(row=6, column=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of width and height if you want static size

```
self.search_results = tk.Label(master, text=self.query, height = 10,width = 40 bg="#eeac41", fg="#000000")
```

Change the values of height and width as per your needs. You can specify only either of these if you want.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. I used that and wrap length to make it all fit.

Comment: Please accept the answer if its what you needed

Comment: @ElliotFontenot

Answer (score -1):

```
 # If you use padx and pady inside the label to set the size. For example : 
 self.search_results = tk.Label(master, text=self.query, bg="#eeac41", fg="#000000", 
 padx= 35, pady=25)
```